# Composer error while trying to create a project with Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I want to create a project with Laravel 5.0 so I typed `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel 5.0` but it returns this **Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.8 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.6 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.5 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.35 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.34 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.33 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.32 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.31 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.29 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.28 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.27 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.26 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.25 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.24 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.23 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.22 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.21 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.20 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.2 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.19 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.18 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.17 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.15 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.14 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.13 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.12 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.11 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.10 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework 5.0.30 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.30, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.
```

I don't why I receive this error, because my PHP version is *7.4.8* and I just downloaded and installed Composer.

So if you know how can I solve this problem, please let me know, I would really appreciate that...

Thnak

Comment: welcome to SO ..enable `ext-mcrypt` in php.in  https://websiteforstudents.com/install-php-7-2-mcrypt-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which parts of that error message are unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

for windows go to your `php` installed folder and edit `php.ini`

add or uncomment this line

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

and

download `php_mcrypt.so.dll`  from https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mcrypt/1.0.3/php_mcrypt-1.0.3-7.4-nts-vc15-x64.zip

and put `xampp\php\ext\`

Comment: I'm on windows, what is the syntax for composer on windows

Comment: @fojbiu may i know what stack you are using like `xamp`.?

Comment: Yes, it is xampp

Answer (score 0):

**Windows:**

This will work if you have mcrypt extension dll file already present

1. Edit `php.ini`
2. add `extension=mcrypt.so` on Dynamic Extension section
3. restart server

If mcrypt not present.

Install mcrypt dll file from below link based on your php version
https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.3/windows

place your dll file at location `F:\xampp\php\ext\`

**Ubuntu:**

Try installing mcrypt extension by below commands, you need to install mcrypt based on your php version

```
//check php version
php -v

//for php version 5
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

//for php version 7.2
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
```

After mcrypt installs properly, go ahead with your laravel installation

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} "5.0.*" --prefer-dist
```

Refer to laravel documentation for [Laravel 5.0 installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation)

Comment: `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\mcrypt.so (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt.so.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: I have updated my answer, please install mcrypt from external url since it is not present

Comment: I did whatever you said but I get: `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "package" "directory" "version".`

Comment: you can try clearing cache if that make it work else there can be something in your project that requires some fixes. For that i'll need more information